# How to make a modified counter animation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I need to create a web page that shows two buttons: "Start" and "Stop". When "Start" is clicked, I need to display an equation every second. For example:

Suppose that the starting number is 100, then in the animation, the web page will first display:

```
100 + 1 = 101
```

And then every second after that, it should display:

```
100 + 2 = 102; 
100 + 3 = 103;
100 + 4 = 104;
```

and so on...every 1 second.

I have been able to create the counter animation, however, I am stuck as to how to progress after this.

**Here is my code so far**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>

  var counter = 100;
  var counterSchedule;

  function startCounterAnimation(){

    counterSchedule = setInterval(showCounter, 1000);
  }

  function showCounter(){

    counter = counter + 1;

    var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counter");
    counterSpan.innerHTML = counter;
  }

  function stopCounterAnimation(){

    clearInterval(counterSchedule);
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <button onClick="startCounterAnimation()">Start Animation</button>
  <button onClick="stopCounterAnimation()">Stop Animation</button>

  <br /><br />

  <span id="counter"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The counter is working. But the stop button isn't working? Is that what you need help with?

Comment: The counter works, but there I don't know how to display the equations as the counter goes up

Comment: A new line of equation every second it passes or updating current equation it passes?

Comment: The current equation needs to update each second by 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out with the code below. Is that what you're looking for?

```js
  var counter = 100;
  var counterSchedule;
  let i = 1;

  function startCounterAnimation(){

    counterSchedule = setInterval(showCounter, 1000);
  }

  function showCounter(){

    counter = counter + 1;
    var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counter");
    counterSpan.innerHTML = `100 + ${i} = ${counter}`;
    i++;
  }

  function stopCounterAnimation(){

    clearInterval(counterSchedule);
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button onClick="startCounterAnimation()">Start Animation</button>
  <button onClick="stopCounterAnimation()">Stop Animation</button>

  <br /><br />

  <span id="counter"></span>
</body>
</html>
```